# Don't touch file upon write if the file was not changed

Tags: save

Occasionally I absentmindedly type `:w` when I'm reading something. This causes the modification time of the file to change and sometimes causes my build system to unnecessarily rebuild a substantial chunk of a project.

Is there a way to set vim to simply not do anything if I try to write a file and it hasn't been changed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extending @lcd047's answer you can use `cabbrev` to modify `w`

```
:cabbrev w <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'up' : 'w')<CR>
```

When you type `:w` you will notice that it will be replaced with `:up` when you press return.

Answer (score 14):

Not directly (that is, the behaviour of `:w` can't be changed), but you can learn to use `:up` instead of `:w`.  It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Just let me add: I use a favourite keymapping for saving, and I have bound to it `:update` instead of `:write` to obtain the Original Poster requirement.